# Possible to capture video and stream it to flash server on realtime in android?

Tags: android, flash, video, ffmpeg, flv

I working on a project where the client side need to capture video and audio from the camera, use some library (proberly ffmpeg) to convert from mp4 to flv and send it to flash server on realtime,in the other side the client need to get flv and convert it to video type of android on real time. Is it possible to do??

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

If you use Adobe Air (with or without Flex), your client can access an Android device's camera directly. You can then use a [NetConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html) and [NetStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html) to publish the camera feed directly to a Flash Media Server, without having to transcode the video.

It really can be as [straight forward as this example shows](http://blog.ninethsense.com/publish-and-receive-webcam-with-flex-on-flash-media-server/) :)